# AJAX and file_get_contents

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a script which uses file_get_contents and I then decode the returned JSON...

```
$urlone = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=false&screen_name=".$screen_name."&count=".$tweet_count."&page=1"),true);
```

What I would like to achieve is a callback so I can have a nice loader and then animate contents in when complete. Is there a way to use JQuery to do an AJAX call if Javascript is enable and fallback to the default PHP if it is disabled?

Comment: Why having a fallback for someone that has disabled javascript?

Comment: I want to retrieve the data using PHP so it works even if JS is disable but I want to optimise my script to use AJAX so no page refresh. The problem is file_get_contents doesn't work with AJAX call. I need a way around this ie Make JQuery AJAX call to return a POST variable and execute with PHP on AJAX success or alternatively run the PHP function I have now if JS is disabled. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you can do is:

- Confirm js is enabled in a previous request. If enabled link to php file that depends on javascript enabled. if not, link to php file that directly shows output. You could do this with a combination of Meta redirect and Javascript.
- Or call the php file with direct output in an iframe that is inside a `<noscript>` tag, belonging to a  tag that does the jquery.

in the first option you would have file.php link to either fileWithJs.php or fileWithoutJs.php

in the second option you would have something like this:

```
<script>
    // jquery here
</script>
<noscript><iframe src="data.php"></iframe></noscript>
```

Comment: I found a CURL function to use instaed of file_get_contents...

// CURL function to replace file_get_contents
        function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
            $ch = curl_init();
         
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //Set curl to return the data instead of printing it to the browser.
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
         
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
         
            return $data;
        }

Answer (score 2):

PHP doesn't know if the user has JavaScript enabled when it handles the request from the user, at least not on the first request.

Normally you would assume the user has no javascript and enhance from there, but as you want to 'fallback' to PHP, you would need to render the JSON anyway regardless of whether the user had JavaScript functionality - so using JavaScript would now be a tad pointless as you (and the user) already have the data.

Comment: Sorry. Fallback is the wrong phrase. This works with PHP only as it is. I need to enhance with JQuery.